# Conditional formatting on a range with time format

Tags: excel

I've tried with a multiple formulas to get a range of cells highlighted using conditional format.

Condition 1 : Any cell on column A must say "Black"
Condition 2:  Any cell within the range of B:F that have more than 30 minutes

I've tried combining OR and AND because when one of my cells has 1:35 it recognize it as 35 minutes instead of 85 minutes . The cells format on range B:F are on time format but for a reason the "AM" is always there.

I've attached a screenshot with a portion of my data and how is supposed to be highlighted after applying a conditional formatting with both conditions, I should be getting everything highlighted on the rows that are saying "Black" except Monday with value 0:30:00 and Wednesday with value 00:00:03 as these are less than 30 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put a range in your formula. Just apply the rule to the top-left cell in your range (B2 in my case) and as the rows and columns change through the selection, so will the formula change automatically by relative addressing.

```
=AND($A2="Black",B2>TIME(0,30,0))
```

So for cell C3 (say) this would effectively be

```
=AND($A3="Black",C3>TIME(0,30,0))
```

(you can also use .5/24 instead of TIME(0,30,0))

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom , my mistake was using the range on the formula .You're awsome

Answer (score 0):

Time format are stored in Excel as the number of days since january 1st 1900.

All you have to do is consider your hours as 1/24th of a day.

Any cell within the range of B:F that have more than 30 minutes will become a cell with a value greater than `=.5/24`

Comment: I understand that but when you use that information on the formula it does not work : =AND($H11="Black",$I$11:$M$19>0.5/24)